# SQL left join on condition OR other condition

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

i've got a question:

In a query i need to check for replies and interactions, if these are present. i want to know which user it was that made the reply or interaction and include it in my row. I currently have this:

```
SELECT * FROM `alerts` a 
LEFT JOIN `interactions` i ON a.alerts = i.alert_id 
LEFT JOIN `reply` r ON a.alerts = r.alert_id 
LEFT JOIN `users` u ON u.id = r.user_id OR i.user_id 
WHERE (a.user_id = '0' AND r.user_id != '') 
OR (a.user_id = '0' AND i.user_id != '')
```

This somewhat returns what i wan't except that the With the interaction table returns duplicate alert id, The first said  that the police posted the interaction on that alert which is a.user_id 0 and the other returns correct with the user's name. Can someone help me?

Comment: (a.user_id = '0' AND (r.user_id != '' OR i.user_id != '' ))

Comment: Can you give some data with expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your r and i user ID references in the where clause turning it from a left-join to an inner join.  Move those conditions to the join portion, then test for NOT NULL for either of them.

```
SELECT * 
   FROM `alerts` a 
      LEFT JOIN `interactions` i 
         ON a.alerts = i.alert_id 
      LEFT JOIN `reply` r 
         ON a.alerts = r.alert_id 
        AND r.user_id != ''
      LEFT JOIN `users` u 
         ON ( u.id = r.user_id 
           OR u.id = i.user_id )
        AND i.user_id != ''
   WHERE 
      a.user_id = '0'
      AND ( NOT r.user_id IS NULL
           OR NOT i.user_id IS NULL )
```

Comment: Thanks this was the closest answer, i needed to remvoe the AND i.user_id != '' at the on clause for the users and it returned disired results Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In your situation you have for an alert:
 1. An user that is referenced by the table `reply`
 2. An user that is referenced by the table `interactions`

As both users have a different role in your query, I suggest you the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM alerts A
LEFT JOIN interactions I ON I.alert_id = A.alerts
LEFT JOIN users UI ON UI.id = I.user_id
LEFT JOIN reply R ON R.alert_id = A.alerts
LEFT JOIN users UR ON UR.id = R.user_id
WHERE A.user_id = '0'
```

By doing so you can then display the desired fields in your `SELECT` statement.

Hope this will help.